# Error de conversión al convertir el valor varchar al tipo de datos int en un case

Tags: sql-server, script

Tengo una consulta en SQL Server y tengo un dato en una tabla que es varchar pero necesito que en mi consulta se convierta en un int ya que la consulta llena una tabla donde ese campo es int, este es parte de mi código:
`SELECT  CASE WHEN C.id=1 THEN vol ELSE 0 END AS C1,  CASE WHEN C.id=2 THEN vol ELSE 0 END AS C2,  CASE WHEN C.id=3 THEN vol ELSE 0 END AS C3,`

donde vol es el valor varchar de mi tabla, intente con cast y convert y no me funciono, sigue dando el mismo error.

Agradecida de su ayuda:)

Comment: ¿Y si nos muestras como eran esos cast/convert que hacías?

Comment: Prueba `select case C.id when 1 then try_convert(int, vol) else 0 end as C1,` ... y busca los valores nulos, que serán errores de conversión